# How to make an alert dialog with a spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

I know how to make an alert dialog but I need to make one with a spinner so that when it pops up the person will have an option as to what happens. Does anyone have the code for an alert dialog with a spinner or know any good tutorials?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);

View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, null);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

// set dialog message

alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("My Dialog..");
alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
// create alert dialog
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

final Spinner mSpinner= (Spinner) promptsView
        .findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
final Button mButton = (Button) promptsView
        .findViewById(R.id.myButton);

// reference UI elements from my_dialog_layout in similar fashion

mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemClicked());

// show it
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

where

**`my_dialog_layout`** is the popup layout which you contains the Spinner **`mySpinner`**

**EDIT :**

```
public class OnSpinnerItemClicked implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Clicked : " +
                    parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
```

Comment: onSpinnerItemclicked is underlined red

Comment: Yes sir, as it should be! You need to define it! Is it the first time you are working with spinners ?

Comment: yes, how do I define it

Comment: Edited my answer to add that part of the code.

Comment: this is what I set the OnSpinnerItemClicked to    private static final      OnItemSelectedListener OnSpinnerItemClicked = null;

Comment: `mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new onSpinnerItemClicked());`

Comment: I suggest you have a look at how a Spinner works. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Comment: I did, for some reason it still wants me to initialize the variable when the class is made,

Comment: Then you must doing something wrong. Could you please post your code ? Edit your question and add the code that you are using.

Comment: nvm I fixed it, thank you very much, I had to change (OnSpinnerItemClicked) to (new OnSpinnerItemClicked())

Comment: If you look at my code closely, you would find that even I did the same after I added the code of the class. I also mentioned it in the comments above. Anyway, great that you solved it.  :)