# android date picker year only

Tags: android, datepicker

hello guys I am developing an application and I need to display a date picker. This date picker needs to display only the year. Does any one know how to limit the date picker to show only years.
kind regards 
and thanks

Comment: Use [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).

Comment: here is complete source http://androidexample.com/In_this_example_creating_a_date_picker_to_pick_day__month_year_of_date/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set its bounds using:

```
setMinDate(long minDate)
setMaxDate(long maxDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom date picker using Spinner(populated with year you want) in Dialog box. [How to make an alert dialog with a spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268455/how-to-make-an-alert-dialog-with-a-spinner)